# write json to dataframe (different amount of attributes, some are empty)

Tags: python, sql, json, pandas

Sorry, couldn't find the solution to integrate in the code and need help.
The whole task - take info per api from accounting program then write to database.
The problem is, that the items of the api have 1) different amount of attributes - they can be omitted (e.g. remark (on screenshot), shippingDate (not on screenshot) 2) empty attributes (files on screenshot) 3) nested attributes (voucherItems (on screenshot)
[image]
[image]
In powerAutomate the solution was simple - I've assigned every attribute by address to variable, then used them in sqlQuery.
In Python I've decided to use dataFrames and have encountered a problem.
I can't normalise nested json saving all the attributes of the parent node if there is an error for example 'files' is empty. [image]
But I need to be accurate and get right relation of the voucher to all voucherItems and preserve the amount of columns, as I'll need dataFrame for taking tuples to use in query (see screenshot).
[image]

```
dataFrameVouchers=pandas.DataFrame(columns = ['id', 'organizationId', 'type', 'voucherStatus', 'voucherNumber','voucherDate', 'shippingDate', 'dueDate', 'totalGrossAmount', 'totalTaxAmount', 'taxType', 'useCollectiveContact', 'contactId','remark', 'amount', 'taxAmount', 'taxRatePercent', 'categoryId', 'files', 'createdDate', 'updatedDate', 'version'])
dataFrameVoucherItems=[]
dataFrame=[]
dataFrameVoucher=[]

def voucherItems(dataFrame):
    dataFrameVoucherItems.append(pandas.json_normalize(
    dataFrame, record_path =['voucherItems']
        )
    )
    return dataFrameVoucherItems

def vouchers(bearer, accept, voucherId):
    headers = {"Authorization": bearer,
                "Accept": accept}
    response = requests.get("https://api.lexoffice.io/v1/vouchers/"+str(voucherId),
    headers = headers)
    vouchers = response.json()
    data = json.dumps(vouchers)
    content = json.loads(data)
    meta = list(pandas.DataFrame([content]))
    dataFrameVoucher = pandas.json_normalize(content)
    dataFrameVoucherItems = (pandas.json_normalize(
            content, meta = ['id', 'organizationId', 'voucherType', 'voucherStatus', 'voucherNumber','voucherDate', 'shippingDate', 'dueDate', 'totalGrossAmount', 'totalTaxAmount', 'taxType', 'useCollectiveContact', 'contactId',
            'remark', 'files', 'createdDate', 'updatedDate', 'version'], record_path='voucherItems', errors='ignore'
        )
    )
    dataFrame = pandas.concat([dataFrameVoucher,dataFrameVoucherItems], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
    dataFrame.to_csv(filename, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
    print(type(data))

def main():
    vouchers(bearer, accept, voucherId)

if __name__ == "__main__":
```

[image]

Comment: I recommend you to split your problem in smaller pieces, and ask here doubts about the specific pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Have found such a soluion (have used one I found here, but modified, as there was an error, when usin enumerate).

```
    def vouchers(bearer, accept, voucherId):
    headers = {"Authorization": bearer,
                "Accept": accept}
    response = requests.get("https://api.lexoffice.io/v1/vouchers/"+str(voucherId),
    headers = headers)
    vouchers = response.json()
    if not vouchers['files']:
            vouchers['files']=[{}]
    file = vouchers['id']
    data = json.dumps(vouchers)
    content = json.loads(data)
    meta = list(pandas.DataFrame([content]))
    dataFrameVoucherItems = (pandas.json_normalize(
            content, meta = ['id', 'organizationId', 'voucherType', 'voucherStatus', 'voucherNumber','voucherDate', 'shippingDate', 'dueDate', 'totalGrossAmount', 'totalTaxAmount', 'taxType', 'useCollectiveContact', 'contactId',
            'remark', 'files', 'createdDate', 'updatedDate', 'version'], record_path='voucherItems', errors='ignore'
        )
    )
    return dataFrameVoucherItems
```